# Mobile menu not closing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, responsive, brooklyn

I'm facing issue on mobile menu when click on menu it open the menu and close on it closes and works nicely.

But when click of specific menu item its not closing and just blinking once and again it shows as it is.

Its only one page and click on menu item it jumps on specific section and i have use wordpress 'brooklyn theme' may be there is something wrong with links of menu items.

Tired below code

```
jQuery("#ul-nav-menu li").click(function(){
    jQuery("#nav-menu-area").css('display','none');  //tried this isn't working
    jQuery("#nav-menu-area").hide();  //tried this isn't working
    clicked = 0;
    return false; //tried this if theme js called then try to stop here
    e.preventdefault() //tried this if theme js called then try to stop here
});
```

Below is html code

```
<nav id="nav-menu-area">
    <ul id="ul-nav-menu" class="ul-nav-menu">
        <li><a href="#top">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-section">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services-section">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#models-section">our models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-section">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: post your html code

Comment: added  html code

Comment: its theme issue i think as js is working but i think theme js overwriting